# Why do I need to wrap some importings with figure brackets {} in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I found a strange situation in ES6. For example, I'm using npm packages `react` and `react-router`. I want to import them to the file:

```
import React from "react";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
```

The strange situation is that I need to wrap `browserHistory` in figure brackets, but I don't need to wrap React. What is the reason?

```
import { React } from "react"; // React is undefined
import browserHistory from "react-router"; // browserHistory is undefined
```

What's the reason that I need to customize my import?

Comment: [MDN - export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) [MDN - import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)

Comment: Wild guess: there is a default exports, which is used by React. So in browserHistory you are exporting that method and in react you are getting the default which has a different name, or getting the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 modules differentiate between two kinds of exports: default exports and other exports.

Every module can have at most *one* default export. A default export is kind of like the “main attraction” of a module. It’s supposed to be the one thing that you probably meant the module to have. All other exports fit into the other category.

So a module can have any number of exports (even zero), of which at most one can be a default export.

On the [`export` side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) of the syntax, a default export is simply marked by adding a `default` after the `export` keyword:

```
// this is a normal export
export var foo = 'foo';

// this is a default export
var bar = 'bar';
export default bar;
```

On the [`import` side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) of the syntax, this gets a it more complicated: Default exports are imported outside of curly braces. All other exports are imported inside curly braces.

```
import bar, { foo } from 'some-module';
```

This would import the default exported member of the module as `bar` and also import the (named) other export `foo`. Note that default exports do not have a fixed name: The original name of the member at export time does not matter. Instead, you give it some name when importing it. So you could also write this instead:

```
import baz, { foo } from 'some-module';
```

This would still import the same default export from the module, but give it a different name. Other imports however are required to have the correct name, since that’s what’s used to identify them. You can however give them a different name by using the `as` keyword.

There are a few more things to know when using the [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) statements. You should check MDN for a full description of them.

Comment: `default` is special because it's a keyword, but at it's core, it's just a name for an export like any other name. You can't export two things with the same name, whether the name is `default` or something else. Also note `export default bar;` isn't the only way to export a default. You can also do `export {bar as default};`, which has the added benefit that you'll get live binding of `bar` too.

Answer (score 0):

If the module you are importing has a default export, then you do not have to use the { } syntax to access the given export. Named (non-default) exports must be accessed via the { } syntax. A module can have a default export as well as many named exports.

An example of that would be React which is a default export, but the module also has a named export of Component. To import both of these exports the syntax: `import React, { Component } from 'react'` would be used.

Comment: "If the module you are importing has a default export, then you do not need the { } syntax" --- this is vague. `import React, { Component } from 'react';` is a common statement. Irregardless of presence of the default export you may or may not need to use named imports.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms I edited my answer to hopefully fix the issue my original answer had. Let me know or edit further if my point isn't getting across very well.

Comment: "to access a property" --- it's not a "property", but a named export.

Comment: `s/to access an export/to access named exports/`

Comment: @poke You could always `import {default as React} from` instead of `import React from` if you wanted.

Comment: @httpNick Feels like it could still use some work. It's not whether the module has many exports, it's whether you are trying to import one of those or the default.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Interesting, didn’t actually know that was possible. Thanks!